# putting a point on the right side of a div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to put a point on the right side of a relative (no defined width) div.

HTML (using Wordpress and Bootstrap)

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
        <h2 class="sml-title"><?php the_category(' - '); ?></h2> 

...
```

CSS

```
.sml-title {
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px;
color: #fff;
background-color: #4ad2dc;
}

.sml-title:after {
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
border: solid transparent;
content: " ";
height: 0;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
pointer-events: none;
border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
border-left-color: #88b7d5;
border-width: 30px;
margin-top: -30px;
}
```

the problem I'm running into is that the arrow goes all the way to the right side of the screen. I want it to go right after the sml-title. But I can't set a width on the sml-title because i don't control the content.

Trying to accomplish this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `position: absolute`, it will position the element within the nearest parent which is either `position: relative` or `absolute`. In your case, `.sml-title` has neither of those properties, so `.sml-title:after` is not positioned within `.sml-title`.

If you want your `::after` pseudoelement to be positioned within `.sml-title`, you'll need to add `position: relative` or `absolute` to `.sml-title`

Comment: that works, I have to set a height though so as long as the font and position stay the same across all browsers it should work, thank you

Comment: @user3550879 no worries!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the shape as either of the two ways-

```css
.arrow {
   border-right: 33px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 130px;
  border-bottom: 34px solid black;
 
}
.invert {
  -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: transform: rotateX(180deg);
  ;
}
#base {
    background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 134px;
  margin-left: 33px;
  /* margin-top: 51px; */
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}


#base:before {
  border-bottom: 35px solid red;
  border-left: 36px solid transparent;
  border-right: 34px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  width: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
<div class="arrow invert"></div>
<div id="base"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
h2{
background: #000;
color: #fff;
float: left;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 20px 50px 20px 20px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;

   min-width: 200px;
}
h2:before, h2:after {
content: '';
display: block;
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 30px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
border-left: 30px solid #fff;
position: absolute;
right: -10px;
transform: rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
h2:before {
top: -20px;
transform: rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
h2:after {
bottom: -20px;
transform: rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<h2 class="sml-title">TITLE</h2>
```

Comment: I am using safari to view your snippet and the arrow is pointing the wrong way

Comment: please check now. added `-webkit-` prefix for transform